# Python- Return a verified variable from a function to the main program

Tags: function, validation, input, while-loop, integer

Can anyone please direct me to an example of where one can send a user input variable to a checking function or module & return the validated input assigning / updating the initialised variable?. I am trying to re-create something I did in C++ many years ago where I am trying to validate an integer! In this particular case that the number of bolts input in a building frame connection is such. Any direction would be greatly appreciated as my internet searches and trawls through my copy of Python A Crash Course have yet to shed any light! Many thanks in anticipation that someone will feel benevolent towards a Python newbie!
Regards Steve

Below is one on my numerous attempts at this, really I would just like to abandon and use While and a function call. In this one apparently I am not allowed to put > (line 4) between str and int, this desite my attempt to force N to be int - penultimate line!

```
def int_val(N):
    #checks
    # check 1.  n > 0 for real entries
    N > 0
    isinstance(N, int)
    N=N
    return N
    print("N not ok enter again")
    #N = input("Input N the Number of bolts  ")
    

# Initialiase N=0
#N = 0

# Enter the number of bolts
N = input("Input N the Number of bolts  ")
int_val(N)

print("no of bolts is", N)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks DjaouadNM, rhurwitz has solved this one, with a really good bit of code to save for future use for this task of validating integer inputs - possibly one to save away. All the best Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you have in mind? It takes advantage of the fact that using the built-in `int` function will convert a string to an integer if possible, but otherwise throw a `ValueError`.

```
def str_to_posint(s):
    """Return value if converted and greater than zero else None."""
    try:
        num = int(s)
        return num if num > 0 else None
    except ValueError:
        return None

while True:
    s = input("Enter number of bolts: ")
    if num_bolts := str_to_posint(s):
        break
    print(f"Sorry, \"{s}\" is not a valid number of bolts.")
    
print(f"{num_bolts = }")
```

Output:

```
Enter number of bolts:  twenty
Sorry, "twenty" is not a valid number of bolts.
Enter number of bolts:  20
num_bolts = 20
```

Comment: Perfect works really well thank you! I few new commands I have learned here! All the best Steve

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Go ahead and accept the answer when you get a chance so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

def str_to_posint(s):
"""Return value if converted and greater than zero else None."""
try:
num = int(s)
return num if num > 0 else None
except ValueError:
return None

while True:
s = input("Enter number of bolts: ")
if num_bolts := str_to_posint(s):
break
print(f"Sorry, "{s}" is not a valid number of bolts.")

print(f"{num_bolts = }")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).